# Timeformat timelineview Bat module

Tags: 7, javascript

I had a reservations system with the .bat module.  But I want to change the timeformat in my timelineview from am/pm to 24hours time notation. I have been looking in batfullcalander and the library of fullcalendar and fullcalanderscheduler. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the timeformat I had to change TimeFormat             from            .replace(':m', ':mm') to  .replace('h', 'HH') in fullcalendar.js